# Search for sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a sql function in oracle
create or replace function testfunc.....

Compile it succesfully. When i verify all_procedures system table it's not there. 
 select * from all_procedures where procedure_name like '%testfunc%';

Not sure whether i am looking at the correct system table

Comment: If you actually want the function to be named `testfunc`, you need to use `create or replace function "testfunc"` - although you probably don't want to...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you are using double-quoted identifiers to enforce case-sensitivity (something you almost certainly don't want to do), Oracle will always store identifiers in upper case in the data dictionary.  So you would want

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_procedures
 WHERE procedure_name = 'TESTFUNC'
```

Comment: Did you find your procedure in all_procedures view??? I can't find it,when I created...:? strange..It shows me just package specifications and package bodies... Please inform me did you find or not? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Log in as system or sys as sysdba and query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_objects 
WHERE object_name LIKE '%TESTFUNC%'
AND object_type='FUNCTION';
```

or

Log in as your user and query:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name LIKE '%TESTFUNC%'
```